# putasynch is not successful

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, webapi

for some reason it gives me false  in if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)

```
  string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
        StringContent content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.PutAsync(client.BaseAddress + "api/Journal", content).Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) { }
```

Comment: There are about 10 million reasons for this

Comment: is my syntax at least correct???

Comment: You need debug your code for `api/Journal` action to check which line makes error.

Comment: Even if result is unsuccessful you still can get body of the response. Response Status and Body are first candidates to be checked here

Comment: i am sorry, i don't understand i am new to this.